# bash Bad substitution while trying to map directory

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to map a path to a working directory here is the command code

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --privileged -it -v ${/home/segun/tf3d}:/tf3d -w/tf3d/ops tensorflow/tensorflow:custom-op-gpu-ubuntu16
```

the error is:

```
 bash: ${/home/segun/tf3d}:/tf3d: bad substitution
```

the documentation says:

```
  docker run --runtime=nvidia --privileged  -it -v ${PWD}:/working_dir -w /working_dir  tensorflow/tensorflow:custom-op-gpu-ubuntu16
```

Answer (score 1):

`${PWD}` is a variable of the current working directory, so if you hardcode you don't need the `${}`.

so just instead of `${/home/segun/tf3d}` it should be just the path `/home/segun/tf3d`

or run with `${PWD}` in the folder `/home/segun/tf3d`

also, you miss a space between -w and the working folder path

Comment: Flaxon thank you, it works.